# Show help in c# showing proper topic but wrong content in CHM

Tags: winforms, chm

Below is the code I am using to show my CHM file.

```
Help.ShowHelp(control, HelpFile, HelpNavigator.Topic, topic);

topic="/foo_Manual/foo-Define_Technologies_1-Chapter9/Defining_foo.htm.";
```

It is opening the proper html widow in the right; however, the left side's contents tab is always pointing to 1st chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
Help.ShowHelp(Control, HelpFileName, HelpNavigator.TopicId, TopicID);
```

Comment: I don't have a topic ID with me only topic names are available.Any idea on how to get topic ID of Chm file ?

Comment: Ask the topic ID to the person who has created "CHM" file. At the time of creation they will provide it.

Comment: Any idea on where do we get MapID in hhc or hhk file ?

Comment: Ask the topic ID to the person who has created "CHM" file. At the time of creation they will provide it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23749/discussion-between-shri-and-anandkumar)

Comment: OK i tried giving some topic ID like this Help.ShowHelp(Control, HelpFileName, HelpNavigator.TopicId, "25"); then it is opening the html page wrt 25 but the respective content is not pointed on the left side

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the way your CHM file is compiled and/or the last user action.

But you need AutoSync too (see attached picture of HTMLHelp Workshop).

Please note one that the last visited tab is saved to a hh.dat file: When a CHM file is compiled, you can define the default tab displayed when the file is opened. If a user opened one of the other tabs (e.g. the index) and closes the file, the next time the file is opened, it will be opened in the Index tab.

Following code is working for me:

```
            Help.ShowHelp(this.btnOpenHelpShowTopic, helpProvider1.HelpNamespace, HelpNavigator.Topic, @"/Garden/flowers.htm");
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort let me try this